# If one congruence from each given set of congruences is satisfied, then all congruences in all the sets are satisfied.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, terminology

*If this is a duplicate in any way, please forgive me; at the time of asking I don't know what to search for and number theory is not my forté. This is primarily a [terminology](/questions/tagged/terminology) question with an additional request for some previous uses of the phenomenon in question. I hope this is narrow enough a focus.*

### Background:

This is inspired by some research of mine and my supervisor's at Essex. See [here](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/jgth-2021-0131/html) for the paper it is derived from.

### An Example:

Consider the following three sets of congruences for $j,k,l\in\Bbb Z$, modulo a fixed number $n\in \Bbb N$:

$$
(A)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
2k &\equiv 0\\
2j &\equiv 2l
\end{array}\right.$$

$$(B)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
k &\equiv 2j\\
k &\equiv 2l\\
2k&\equiv j+l\\
0&\equiv j+l
\end{array}\right.$$

$$(C)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
l&\equiv j+k\\
j &\equiv l+k
\end{array}\right.$$

If one from each of $(A),(B),(C)$ holds, then *all* congruences in *all* of $(A),(B),(C)$ hold. The proof is fairly tedious and not very enlightening: I just checked each combination, knowing from Bogley & Parker [1, Lemma 5.1] that, if one from each of $(A)$ and $(C)$ holds, then all of $(A)$ and $(C)$ holds.

### The Question:

> Fix $n\in\Bbb N$ and fix nonempty sets $I,J$. Suppose we have variables $(a_i)_{i\in I}\in\Bbb Z^I$ and sets $(S_j)_{j\in J}$ of congruences of the $a_i$ modulo $n$. Suppose that if there exists $c_j\in S_j$ for all $j$ such that $c_j$ holds true, then all $c\in S_j$ holds for all $j$. Has such a phenomenon been studied before (in other contexts than referenced here)? If so, does it have a name?

### Thoughts:

If $|S_j|=1$ for all $j\in J$, then the property is trivial.

I am reminded of the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). I don't know why (beyond just that it has a system of congruences).

This is not something I think I can answer myself.

Please help :)

### References:

[1] W. A. Bogley and F. W. Parker, *Cyclically presented groups with length four positive relators*, J. Group Theory 21 (2018), no. 5, 911–947.

Comment: Is there any reason behind the downvote?

Comment: Lots of drive by downvoters here.